# android -set background for imageview when touch it

Tags: android

This is an image of what I mean :

[image]

This is an image of imageview on AppBar when I touch it . By default it doesn't have any background and it looks like this :

[image]

But when I hold my hand on it , it looks like the first image.

This happens on pre lolipop too ,I took this image from android 4.4 .

How can I make some thing like this ?

Comment: if you don't want ripple effect just to change the background use selector

Answer (score 2):

Touch feedback in material design provides an instantaneous visual confirmation at the point of contact when users interact with UI elements. The default touch feedback animations for buttons use the new [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) class, which transitions between different states with a ripple effect.

You can use [Ripple effect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)  for your requirement

1. [Ripple Touch Effect For Demo Testing](http://appsdevelopment-for-mobiles.blogspot.in/2014/11/android-l-ripple-touch-effect.html)